# How to hide a div inside a iframe after the page loads

Tags: html, css, reporting-services

I have a iframe linking to a SSRS report. And i need to hide the control bar at the top. From inspect element i find a this `<div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl05" class="MenuBarBkGnd ToolBarBackground" style="zoom: 1;">`
Is it possible to hide this div when the page loads using a `<style></style>` tag in the iframe?

Here is the iframe code
`<iframe width="800" height="2000px" frameborder="0" src="https://misreporting/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fWC_REPORTS%2fREG%2fwc_studentProfile&stu_id=!{ViewData.Model.stuDim.stu_id}&acy_id=!{ViewData.Model.stuDim.acy_id}&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false"></iframe>`

Comment: Please could you put your code into your question so we can take a look. In general you can’t restyle contents of an iframe but it may be possible to hide something.

Comment: @AHaworth added

Comment: I think you cant hide elements from code inspectors

Comment: @Panken0 I can manually add visibility : none when i inspect element and that does what i want, but obviously that goes when i refresh the page

Comment: oh, you mean hide the div from the view, you tried 'display : none' using  'MenuBarBkGnd' class?

Comment: @Panken0 how would i go about hiding that in the <iframe> tag

Comment: Please check the url you have given.

Comment: @AHaworth its a local server. using azuread authentication so you would have access

Comment: Ok, so we can’t see how it sits within its frame, sorry can’t help.

Comment: @AHaworth This is the best i can do https://ibb.co/02MzT4b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by adding a styles.css file to the SQL server directory. Hiding the div in that file then referencing it in the url on the iframe